# asp.net core self hosted app leaks on webhost respawn

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, memory-leaks

I have a self-hosted asp.net core app that needs to occassionally respawn its WebHost with a new context. App registers a shared resource as a singleton in asp.net DI container.

```
            services.AddSingleton<MyDep>();
```

Controller depends on a share resource:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    public MyDep Dep { get; }

    public ValuesController(MyDep dep)
    {
        Dep = dep;
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] {
            new string(Dep.Content),
            "value2" };
    }
 }
```

It leaks the resources bound to the previous instance. I reproduced the problem using a demo app (slightly modified asp.net core api project template).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        while (true)
        {
            p.Boot(args);
            GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
        }
    }

    private void Boot(string[] args)
    {
        webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();
        webHost.RunAsync();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        webHost.StopAsync().Wait();
        webHost.Dispose();
    }
```

I am seeing n instances of controller where n is number of http requests to the controller - controller is not being disposed at all.
Profiler indicates a long path to root with System.Threading.OverlappedData at the end of the chain. Could you suggest what is wrong with this setup? 
[sample app](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f5rGNOcYBulnO-JH20KCCCx2GjGOFqxI)

[path to root](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k2RybN3QBPsMT3opZGhH5EuKMoX5ClFg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've shown the wrong trace for the problem described. The context was not properly released nevertheless.

I found a solution: IApplicationLifecycle.StopApplication as described here -> https://www.blakepell.com/asp-net-core-ability-to-restart-your-site-programatically-updated-for-2-0

The context is being released properly and memory footprint is not growing infinitely anymore

Answer (score 1):

> I am seeing n instances of controller where n is number of http requests to the controller

That's the expected behavior. Controllers are created for each request by default.

From [your snapshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k2RybN3QBPsMT3opZGhH5EuKMoX5ClFg) I don't see there are multiple `MyDep` instances. The snapshot shows the instances of `Func<ValueController, MyDep>`, which is not a singleton as expected. If you invoke the delegate, you will get the same instance of `MyDep` among different requests. Generally speaking, there is nothing wrong here. You are tracing the wrong type.